# Why does strftime() not work in Sqlite when dates are stored as ticks?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have the following code:

```
    [Test]
    public void SqliteTest()
    {
        var insertQuery = @"insert into MetricData (Date) Values (@date)";
        var selectQuery = @"select strftime('%Y',Date) as 'year', Date from MetricData";

        var connectionString = "Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;DateTimeFormat=Ticks;";
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            db.Open();
            DatabaseSchemaBuilder.InitializeSchema(db);

            var testDate = DateTime.Now;
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(insertQuery, db))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", testDate);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(selectQuery, db))
            {
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    var queriedDate = reader.GetDateTime(1);
                    var year = reader.GetString(0);

                    Assert.AreEqual(testDate, queriedDate);
                    Assert.AreEqual("2013", year);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, the first assertion passes but the second one fails, with the year equalling to 1968 (other format values are also incorrect, month comes back as 19 for example).

When looking at the raw query output, the year result is `1968` and the Date is `635120225608999130`.

Why is `strftime()` not working properly in this instance?

**Edit:**
Just to add, the Date column I have defined as `Date integer`.  Also, if I do not include `DateTimeFormat=Ticks` in the connection string all assertions pass.

Comment: So, the `Assert.AreEqual("2013", year)` is where the error pops-up you're saying?

Comment: Correct, the `Assert.AreEqual(testDate, queriedDate);` assert passes

Answer (score 1):

`Date` as `Integer` in `Sqlite` uses `Unix Time` which allows the oldest date of `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`. Thus the 1968 year value would be an error and would not pass the `Assert.AreEqual("2013",year)`.

See [Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

And removing `DateTimeFormat=Ticks;` in your connection string means you are going to use the default `ISO8601` which allow date prior to `1970-01-01` and most likely the reason your Assert passes.

See [Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: It has nothing to do with using old dates.  I'm using a date from 2013 (as can see from the code).  The problem is sqlite is incorrectly interpreting the date as 1968 and reading the time wrong.

Comment: I know it's not the year in your code (i.e. 2013) but from your table, that's why I am pointing that one out. Anyway Date is a reserved word, have you tried putting a square bracket on it like [Date]?

Comment: It's good to know, and makes me wonder if I need to convert c# ticks to unix time prior to running strftime().  I haven't tried to putting the brackets in, but since it works correctly without using ticks I doubt that would be the issue.